# meteor で smtp.gmail を使うプログラムが、localhost で動いて、meteor.com で動かない

Tags: gmail, meteor

meteor deploy すると、標準では Mailgun を使うことになりますが、代わりに gmail を使いたいと思っています。最小限のテストプログラムで試したのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

Error invoking Method 'sendMail': Internal server error [500]

どうすれば、gmailを使えるようにできるでしょうか。

※localhost（windows8.1）で同じコードを試すと、期待通りにメールを送れて、エラーも出ません。
※gmailのアカウントの方は、アカウント」＞「ログインとセキュリティ」＞「接続済みのアプリとサイト」＞「安全性の低いアプリの許可: 有効」に設定しています。

```
// test.html  
<head>  
  <title>test</title>  
</head>  

<body>  
  {{> test}}  
</body>  

<template name="test">  
  <input type="button" value="send mail">  
</template>  

// test.js  
if (Meteor.isClient) {  
  Template.test.events({  
    'click [type="button"]':function(){  
      var dateTime = new Date();  
      console.log(dateTime);  
      Meteor.call('sendMail',dateTime);  
    }  
  });  

}  

if (Meteor.isServer) {  

  Meteor.startup(function () {  
    var gmailAccount = {'eml':'user@gmail.com','pwd':'************'};  
    var st = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(gmailAccount.eml) + ':' + gmailAccount.pwd + '@smtp.gmail.com' + ':465/'; check(st,String);  
    process.env.MAIL_URL = st;  
  });  

  Meteor.methods({  
    'sendMail':function(dateTime){  
      var to = 'user@gmail.com'; check(to,String);  
      var from = 'user@gmail.com'; check(from,String);  
      var subject = 'test'; check(subject,String);  
      var text = 'Time:' + dateTime; check(text,String);  
      var sendObj = {'to':to, 'from':from, 'Reply-To':from, 'subject':subject, 'text':text};  
      Email.send(sendObj);  
    }  
  });  

}
```

Comment: パスワードをエンコードしないのは意図通りですか？あと、ポート番号を 587、25 とそれぞれ変更するとなにか変化ありますか？

Comment: パスワードは、meteorのドキュメントのEmailの項に、”the MAIL_URL environment variable should be of the form smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/”　とあるので、このとおりにまずはやってみました。 

ポート587で試しても、465と同じ症状です。25はやっていなかったのですが、いま試してみたら、localでも動きませんでした。 

まとめると、こんな具合ですね・・・ 

> port 25: 'local:3000': InternalError, 'meteor.com': InternalError 
> port 465: 'local:3000': work, 'meteor.com': InternalError 
> port 587: 'local:3000': work, 'meteor.com': InternalError

Comment: もしパスワードにURLで使用出来ない文字を使っている場合は、エンコードが必要です。その点以外でコードにおかしなところはなさそうなので、環境の問題っぽいですね。Gmailの関連しそうなヘルプがあったのでまとめてみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分のアカウントで試したところ Gmailの認証で弾かれました。
[Googleのヘルプ](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563?vid=1-635762560052965216-324165554)に書かれている手順で *.meteor.com から Gmail 経由でメール送信が出来ましたので試してみてください。

私の場合は、手順の最後に書かれてる  https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha にアクセスすると送信できました。

Comment: ご指摘のとおりにしてみたら、できました。
firefox 上で、普段使いのとは別に、このテスト用にメールアドレスを設定して使っていましたので、いったんプロファイルごと削除して、テストアカウントでプロフィールを綺麗に作り直し、そのアカウント上で、ご指摘のGoogleアカウントヘルプをやってみたら、うまくいきました。
ありがとうございました！